# Assign a small number to unsigned long long data-type without casting

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I became a little bit confuse about assigning a small number to a big data-type variable, for example in my `code` **([checkout online](http://cpp.sh/4ankr))** :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned long long num = 5000000000;
  unsigned long long num2 = static_cast<unsigned long long>(5000000) * static_cast<unsigned long long>(1000);
  unsigned long long num3 = 5000000 * 1000UL;       // Casting 1000 to long data-type
  unsigned long long num4 = 5000000 * 1000;
  std::cout << num << std::endl << num2 << std::endl << num3 << std::endl << num4;
  
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
5000000000
5000000000
5000000000
705032704
```

I know about ***literal casting*** and `static_cast` feature in c++ and also about the compiler behavior that always casting with the biggest data-type in a mathematical statement.

But the problem is here that why the result of statement `unsigned long long num4 = 5000000 * 1000;` is the number `705032704` and not `5000000000`? BTW i know when i cast it like `5000000 * 1000UL;` it gives me `5000000000` (because it cast to largest data-type).

- Why the `unsigned long long num4 = 5000000 * 1000;` statement dont casting automatically to `unsigned long long` data-type without using casting directly?
- Where the number `705032704` come from when `5000000 * 1000` calculated?

Regards!

Comment: Because both `5000000` and `1000` are `int` values, making the result of `5000000 * 1000` an `int`. Which means you have signed integer overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: Check the warnings in "compilation" tab and it may answer your second question. `In function 'int main()':
9:37: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]`

Comment: Also, there's no casting in `1000UL`. The `UL` suffix tells the compiler that the value is an `unsigned long` and not an `int`. It seems you mix up explicit casting and [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) and [literal integer type suffixes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Exactly. The `unsigned __int64 a = 5000 * 5000000;` gives me `warning C4307: '*': integral constant overflow` compiler warning. but i dont know why the `unsigned long long a = 5000UL * 5000000UL;` statement gives me the same warning (I expected that by literal casting the warning would be remove but it didnt) can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Try `unsigned long long a = 5000ULL * 5000000ULL;`, `UL` is for `unsigned long`, `ULL` is for `unsigned long long`, they may be different on different compilers/architectures.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, that's it. the problem solved by your advice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line `unsigned long long num4 = 5000000 * 1000;` consists of three independent parts which are evaluated separately.

- The right-hand-side is evaluated as `int` because all the operands are `int`. The result is not what you expect because of an integer overflow.
- The left-hand-side makes space for an `unsigned long long`.
- The assignment copies the (unexpected) result from the right-hand-side into the space allocated for the variable.

Comment: (5000000 * 1000) % 2^32 = 705032704